# Quick question about Google AdSense policy

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, terms-of-use

Is it against the Google AdSense terms of use to direct users to click on the ads? I mean I'm not gonna put a big flashing arrow or anything but what about "check out our sponsors" or something subtle like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends entirely on your content. From the Terms:

> Encouraging users to click your Google ads is strictly prohibited - whether directly or indirectly, on your own site, on third-party sites or via email.
>
> In order to ensure a good experience for users and advertisers,
>   publishers participating in the AdSense programme may not:
>
> ... Encourage users to click the Google ads using phrases such as "click the ads", "support us", "visit these links" or other similar language.

http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=48182

Comment: Can you clarify? You said it depends, but the passage you quoted made it sound like a definite *no*.

Comment: Sorry, I slightly mis-interpreted your question. No you can't direct users to click in any way. You would be able to say something simple like "Our sponsors" I believe.